# Centre or Centre of mass for Geometry points in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, spatial

Is there a way in SQL Server to work out either

- Happy - the centre of a group of points returned from a query (geometry points), i.e. find the outer limits and return the centre

or

- Very Happy - the centre of a group of points based upon their density like a heat map, or to be closest to the most points possible

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This article might be helpful: http://spatialdbadvisor.com/sql_server_blog/263/alternate-centroid-functions-for-sql-server-spatial

Comment: spatialdbadvisor link was 404 for me.  luckily the archive has it.  https://web.archive.org/web/20180706194821/https://spatialdbadvisor.com/sql_server_blog/263/alternate-centroid-functions-for-sql-server-spatial

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Of_a_finite_set_of_points says that you simply average the X coordinates and the Y coordinates. So (assuming you have x and y columns) your query would be like:

```
SELECT SUM(x)/COUNT(*) as CentreX, SUM(y)/COUNT(Y) as CentreY FROM ...
```

Comment: this is so much simpler than anything I was trying to do with the SQL spatial queries, thank you a lot.